# Android webview launches browser when calling loadurl

Tags: android, android-webview, webviewclient

I created an `Activity` that has a title and a web view in a `LinearLayout`. In the `onResume()` method it calls `webView.loadUrl(url)`. The problem is that the activity first shows the title with the rest of the screen blank, then the device browser is launched with the page for the URL. What I want to see is the page being shown in the `WebView` below the title. What could be the problem?

**Edit**:
Ok, did some further search and found this one:

[Clicking URLs opens default browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378800/android-webview-click-opens-default-browser)

It points to the `WebView` tutorial [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html).

Just implement the web client and set it.

Comment: I mention this because you solved my problem... Thank you.

Comment: @Ray, consider writing an answer to this question, if you has found a solution, and accept it. This will help other people with same problem.

Comment: I had an even nastier problem. It turns out, even a *redirect* will load with the browser if a custom WebViewClient is not used.

Comment: This one also tells about it... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4bIF5In1c8s

Answer (score 902, accepted):

Answering my question based on the suggestions from Maudicus and Hit.

Check the WebView tutorial [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html).
Just implement the web client and set it  **before  loadUrl**. The simplest way is:

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

For more advanced processing for the web content, consider the ChromeClient.

Comment: To avoid WebView to launch the default browser when open initial page.

Comment: Thanks for this unbelievable awesome little piece of witchcraft! +1    ...MINUS ONE FOR YOU, Android...

Comment: Excellent answer. Solved my problem too.

Comment: Does this only work for the initial loading? What if you want to navigate the browser from within the app?

Comment: `myWebView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()` in Kotlin!

Comment: Oh, classic Googlers. They always forget to mention something very important in their android documentation....It is maddening, 80% times when I copy paste their code I have to google "why XYZ does not work" and find an answer on stackoverflow...How hard is it to not half-ass documentation Google?

Answer (score 107):

Use this:

```
lWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Comment: @DigvijaySingh check the original of accepted answer. Originally it didn't have this code. It was added way after this answer

Answer (score 58):

use like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dedline);

    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    myWebView.loadUrl("https://google.com");
}
```

Answer (score 29):

Make your Activity like this.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
WebView browser;

@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // find the WebView by name in the main.xml of step 2
    browser=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.wvwMain);

    // Enable javascript
    browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  

    // Set WebView client
    browser.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

    browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
                }
        });
     // Load the webpage
    browser.loadUrl("http://google.com/");
   }
}
```

Comment: `setJavaScriptEnabled(true)` introduces XSS vulnerabilities into your app. Do not use it if you do not need JavaScript

Comment: The line enabling JavaScript is super important otherwise you'll get `You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.` and googling it will only reveal people having issues with react native and you'll go crazy because JavaScript is already enabled in the browser settings.

Comment: Wini, you can do smth. like this

`@ Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
                    mWebView.goBack();
                } else {
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
        }

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}`

Answer (score 24):

I was facing the same problem and I found the solution 
[Android's official Documentation about WebView](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)

Here is my `onCreateView()` method and here i used two methods to open the urls 

**Method 1** is opening url in Browser and 

**Method 2** is opening url in your desired WebView.

And I am using Method 2 for my Application and this is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   private WebView myWebView;

     @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_webpage_detail, container, false);

      // Show the dummy content as text in a TextView.
      if (mItem != null) {

         /* Method : 1
          This following line is working fine BUT when we click the menu item then it opens the URL in BROWSER not in WebView */
         //((WebView)   rootView.findViewById(R.id.detail_area)).loadUrl(mItem.url);

        // Method : 2
        myWebView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.detail_area); // get your WebView form your xml file
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); // set the WebViewClient
        myWebView.loadUrl(mItem.url); // Load your desired url
    }

    return rootView;
}                                                                                               }
```

Answer (score 9):

If you see [an empty page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850654/android-webview-with-https-loadurl-shows-blank-empty-page), enable JavaScript.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this code...

```
private void startWebView(String url) {

    //Create new webview Client to show progress dialog
    //When opening a url or click on link

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {      
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        //If you will not use this method url links are opeen in new brower not in webview
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {              
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        //Show loader on url load
        public void onLoadResource (final WebView view, String url) {
            if (progressDialog == null) {
                // in standard case YourActivity.this
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(view.getContext());
                progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                progressDialog.show();
            }
        }
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            try{
            if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                progressDialog = null;
            }
            }catch(Exception exception){
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }); 

     // Javascript inabled on webview  
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 

    // Other webview options
    /*
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    */

    /*
     String summary = "<html><body>You scored <b>192</b> points.</body></html>";
     webview.loadData(summary, "text/html", null); 
     */

    //Load url in webview
    webView.loadUrl(url);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Simply Answer you can use like this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         WebView webView = new WebView(this);
         setContentView(webView);
         webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
         webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using **webChromeClient** I'll suggest you to use **webChromeClient** and **webViewClient** together. because **webChromeClient** does not provides **shouldOverrideUrlLoading**. It is okay to use both.

```
        webview.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
        webview.webChromeClient = Callback()

private inner class Callback : WebChromeClient() {
        override fun onProgressChanged(view: WebView?, newProgress: Int) {
            super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress)
           
            if (newProgress == 0) {
                progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            } else if (newProgress == 100) {
                progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Damn, it didn't even occur to me to use both. I use `onPageFinished()` from `WebViewClient` and `onConsoleMessage()` from `WebChromeClient`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that it depends on the formatting of the URL:

- https://example.com/example gets opened in the browser
- https://example.com/example/ (with **/** at the end) gets opened in the webView

My code just uses

```
webview.loadUrl(url)
```

no need to set

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient())
```

at least in my case.
Maybe that's useful for some of you.

Comment: Its still opens in browser with end / not correct answer..

Comment: Actually, I'm finding this same behavior. Not sure how to explain it, but this is what I'm seeing as well.

Answer (score 0):

My problem ended up being that I needed to do a clearHistory before I could switch between sites without opening an external browser.

```
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

        webView_.clearHistory();

        super.onPageFinished(webView_, url);
    }
```