# WebView---jump to device's browser

Tags: android, webview

When I click a button to connect with a URL,the webview show NOTHING but jumped to the device's browser,I added use-permission.

Here is my code:

```
btn_go.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String urlString = et_inputURL.getText().toString();
            if (urlString.startsWith("http://")) {
                webView.loadUrl(urlString);
            } else {
                webView.loadUrl("http://" + urlString);
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2893868/115145

Comment: Possible duplicate of [webview opens default browser, I don't know where to put code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12647476/webview-opens-default-browser-i-dont-know-where-to-put-code)