# WebView not populating

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview

I have a TextView which opens another layout with a webview in.  I want the webview to populate with http://m.twitter.com

However when the textview is clicked it opens the layout and then invokes the browser instead of populating the webview.

Original Layout with textview:-

```
      <TextView
      android:id="@+id/GoToTCContacting"
      android:layout_width="360dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
      android:layout_weight="2"
      android:background="@drawable/border2"
      android:clickable="true"
      android:onClick="GoToTCContacting"
      android:padding="10dp"
      android:text="Contacting"
      android:textColor="#FFF"
      android:textSize="18sp" />
```

Destination layout (t_c_contacting) with WebView

```
      <WebView
      android:id="@+id/TCcontactingView"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Java for function

```
    public void GoToTCContacting(View view)  
{  
    setContentView(R.layout.t_c_contacting); 
    WebView webView =   (WebView)findViewById(R.id.TCcontactingView);
    webView.loadUrl("http://m.twitter.com");
}
```

How can I get it to populate the webview and not invoke the default browser

Comment: You're calling `setContentView()` from an event handler, or where?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean

Comment: i'd assume the url redirects elsewhere and starts the browser for that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement your web client and set it to your WebView :

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Example : http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/58.html

Duplicate : [Android webview launches browser when calling loadurl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746409/android-webview-launches-browser-when-calling-loadurl)