# Android embedded browser cant connect to server on LAN

Tags: android, browser

I've got a simple android app with an embeded browser.  Here it is:

```
WebView webview = new WebView(this);

setContentView(webview);

webview.loadUrl("192.168.1.106");
```

I'm running a web server on '192.168.1.106'. This server is alive and well and accessible through the web browser on the phone.  When I start the app I get a 'Web Page not Available'.  If I change the app to:

```
webview.loadUrl("http://google.com");
```

everything works.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify `http://` even when IP is used.

```
webview.loadUrl("http://192.168.1.106");
```

To force the webpage to always load into WebView (not external browser), add this line before the `loadUrl` call.

```
viewer.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

See this answer: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12802173/2203164)

Comment: This partially fixed it.  However, the app now launches a browser outside of the app when I have http:// 192.168.1.106.  When I have http:// google.com it is loaded in the embedded browser.

Comment: I've updated answer to show, how to force the webpage to load always into ebedded browser.

Answer (score 0):

webview.loadUrl("http://192.168.1.106:8080") put your http port to the end of the ip address