# Kill chrome process

Tags: java, android

I created a new project in Android. We use the following code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.web);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("http://t.co/YoHe3NKrJH");
```

He is opening Chrome.

I need to close it automatically after 10s.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: Chrome? Is it not displayed in your `WebView`?

Comment: Did this not help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746409/android-webview-launches-browser-when-calling-loadurl ? Also check the Page Navigation section from http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html .

Comment: It does not open in webView, this opening Chrome.

Comment: Mind posting you web layout. Its quite strange that it opens Chrome!

Comment: i edit post to put my .xml