# Android - Open URL in a WebView

Tags: android, url, webview

I've a problem with a simple Android application that have WebView inside and a URL to open.
When I try to lanch a App, the URL is opened to Chrome Web Browser, but not in a app.
This is a code snippet in main activity:

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("http://www.example.org");
```

I've following a official guide and more guide searched, but with the same results.

Resolved with this code:

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: and also override `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method

Comment: can you put your whole code?

Comment: Thanks. It's work fine. Sorry for I've reposting a question but I could not get out.

Comment: @robdev ... read my answer if you want , bcause i was facing the same problem and i explained it with two examples  
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746409/android-webview-launches-browser-when-calling-loadurl/32086804#32086804