# Why is the internet not working on emulator but working on real device? (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-emulator

> **NOTE:** This question is not intended to find a solution for a problem. It is directed towards finding information of why is the problem happening.

I created an app, which is supposed to access the internet. ***but*** I didn't add the line

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /
```

to the manifest file, which should lead to an app unable to access the internet. It is not able to access the internet(obviously), in the emulator. However, in my phone, it works perfectly fine (i.e. I can access the Internet through the app!!!).

Why does this happen?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "accessing the Internet through the app"?

Comment: @UgurcanYildirim Thanks for the quick reply. The app has a WebView, and I can open an internet website from it, but I shouldn't be able to (I haven't add the permission in the manifest).

Comment: Yeah, actually it shouldn't be able to. Have you tried (cleaned/rebuilt the project) couple of times just to be sure that IDE successfully built an APK that contains manifest without Internet permission?

Comment: You some time used this permission and remove later ? The permission is granted when you install the app, when you run through the Android Studio, the app don't need newer permissions, so the user will not be prompted during the install. Try Uninstall the APP and install again without the permission (Or find the App info in the Configurations of the device and check the permissions)

Comment: @LucasQueirozRibeiro Mmmm, I am going to be honest here: I am learning to create apps. This is the first time I try to access the internet from an app, I have NEVER ever, not in this nor other app, given such a permission.

Comment: In the first time you have installed this APP the manifest don't have the permission ? What's the Android Version ?

Comment: @LucasQueirozRibeiro The manifest has never been altered, never given such a permission. I have 5.1.1. I uninstalled the app and currently making a test as adviced by Ugurcan Yildirim.

Comment: @UgurcanYildirim Did as adviced, cleaned and rebuilt. Still the same.

Comment: That's strange, i know that in Android 6+ (Marshmallow) the internet permission is not required (but is recommended), so, all APP have internet permission.

Comment: What Url are you trying to access ?

Comment: @UgurcanYildirim Now I see what your first question was about. Actually I am not able to access "through" the app. The app opens another app I have installed on my phone. I think I got confused, in the emulator, the app is unable to "open" other apps in order to access the internet. Am I getting it right now? and, anyway, is this a normal behavior?

Comment: @LucasQueirozRibeiro have a look at my last comment, please (www.google.com is the answer to your last question).

Comment: @Hans see my answer.

Comment: Yes, may be, i figured you are using the WebView component, if you use an Intent, the other app may have the permission not yours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are creating an `Intent` and open url in Chrome or other app than yours, then your app won't need the `INTERNET` permission. However, if your app has a `WebView` as a UI component and you try to load url on this `WebView`, you need that permission.

To avoid `loadUrl(...)` opening browser problem, add this line before calling `loadUrl(...)`:

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Comment: I have a WebView, and used the loadUrl() method. This lead to the app opening the specified url in a browser, is this normal?

Comment: To avoid that problem, see this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12802173/5250273

Comment: Yeah, I just did that, but I wanted to know if it is normal that the method open a browser

Comment: If you're not setting webview client as shown, yeah that happens.

Comment: Only when accessing the internet, right?, if I have an html it will load on the WebView even without the setWebViewClient method, right?

Comment: Just call `setWebViewClient(...)` after you init your `WebView`.

Answer (score 0):

if you run the emulator first and then you got connected to the internet the emulator and your app will not have an internet connection so try closing and opening the emulator again.