# WebView shows source code instead of rendering

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm trying to load a website in a `WebView` and it loads the source code just fine. However i cannot seem to get it to render the website, instead it displays the source code.

I've tried to change the content-type of the returning response on the server-side but no matter what type is indicated only text/plain seems to work in the actual WebView (the WebView disregards the content-type, if I dump the response text/html is indeed implied).

Here is my code;

```
HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
headers.put("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString((Application.getInstance().getUserName() + ":" + Application.getInstance().getUserPassword()).getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP));

String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
WebView webView = ((WebView) findViewById(R.id.ledger_webview));
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.clearCache(true);
webView.loadUrl(url, headers);
```

From what I can tell other people use the same method, I've also looked in the manual which basically says to do the steps I'm doing, but obviously I'm missing something here.

Do I need to pass a flag somewhere, or manually indicate the content-type for the WebView?

**Edit:** This is the response headers from the server

```
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 2559
Content-Type: text/html
```

Comment: To load a URL, I simply use this: `webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com"); // Example URL`

Comment: @Rotwang Ok, so I tried to load the url given your line, and what happens is that the website is opened in a new window (not limited to google.com), in the chrome browser, instead of in the actual WebView.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12802173/2649012

Comment: @Rotwang Still displays the source code instead of actually rendering it.

Comment: That's weird, indeed. Are you still using the first who lines (those which define the "headers")?

Comment: @Rotwang I've tried both with and without them. I'll let the question stand, but I've created a service instead that downloads the HTML and then loads it into the WebView through the `webView.loadData()` method, which works.

Comment: Nice workaround. Possibly, add it as your own answer.