# NEw case of "The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first."

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

**THIS Is My code , i try to open web page in my activity further**

```
class License : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var webv:WebView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_license)

        webv = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webv)
        wvbtn.setOnClickListener{
            setContentView(webv)
            webv.loadUrl("https://www.sona3elghad.ml")

        }
    }
```

**and this is the error**

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.medanis.fneclis, PID: 8525
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:4586)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4427)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4367)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4340)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:458)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:145)
                      at com.medanis.fneclis.License$onCreate$1.onClick(License.kt:23)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5682)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22669)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6276)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)

HELP ME PLEASE and Thank you ^_^

Comment: Well why are you calling setContentView again and passing in your webview?

Comment: i want to open the web page in my owen activity not in chrome or firefox

Comment: So just remove the second setContentView in you onClickListener `loadUrl` will show the webpage

Comment: yes that true but it will open the webpage in chrome or firefox or t*other browsers not in my webview

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746409/android-webview-launches-browser-when-calling-loadurl

Comment: thank you i found the solution there ^_^

Answer (score 0):

```
wvbtn.setOnClickListener{
    setContentView(webv)
    webv.loadUrl("https://www.sona3elghad.ml")
}
```

`setContentView(webv)` this line is causing the error. If you want to load an url into your `WebView`, change your code to the following:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_license)

    webv = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webv)
    webv.loadUrl("https://www.sona3elghad.ml")
}
```

Comment: i want to open the web page after a click in a button this is why i use that wvbtn