# Webpage not opening in webview

Tags: android, android-studio, webview

My Code:

```
String myURL = "https://google.com/";
myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webV) ;
WebSettings mywebS= myWebView.getSettings();
mywebS.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.loadUrl(myURL);
```

it is always asking me permission to open in the system browser.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android webview launches browser when calling loadurl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746409/android-webview-launches-browser-when-calling-loadurl)

Answer (score 0):

You must have to add permisssion for internet in manifest file

```
myWebView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/");
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
    myWebView.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
    return false;
    }
});
```

here setting up a webview client is required

Answer (score 0):

The Easiest way is:

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Add this line.