# How to Set Linear Layout with WebView for onClickListener

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I have a linear layout carrying webview. I have set the id of the LinearLayout to 'lay001'.
My intention is to set the onClickListener of the layout so that onclick, the intent will send data to webview and then to the url i specified.

All my efforts to make it work failed me. Please help me set the java code. Thanks

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lay001"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_bg1">

                <WebView
                    android:id="@+id/webview001"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:accessibilityPaneTitle="The Liturgy"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp">
                </WebView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView001"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="top"
                    android:text="Anglican Hymns Tunes"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:textStyle="italic|bold"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="#DD1A1A"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webview;
    private LinearLayout myLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                     webview = (WebView001) findViewById(R.id.webview001);
                     webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
                     webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: then what's the problem?

Comment: what is that `WebView001` in on click method ? `webview = (WebView001) findViewById(R.id.webview001);` is it correct ?

Comment: You need to bind the linear layout first before applying the onclick event on it. Thats it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing findViewById() of linearlayout.

Try this out :

```
   private LinearLayout myLayout;
   myLayout= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lay001);
```

Also change this :

```
    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview001);
```

To load url :

```
 myLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
     {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
          mWebview.loadUrl("your url");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Onclick it  loads url within App  Is there a way i can make the webview launch using external playstore app url or browser App?

Comment: @Joseph  look for this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746409/android-webview-launches-browser-when-calling-loadurl

Comment: Your answer is still correct. Shortening the playstore URL makes it possible to launch Playstore App onClick. I used bitly.com