# Kotlin WebView - Prevent Opening In New Chrome Browser Window

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

I have inserted the below code into MainActivity.kt in a blank activity.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val url = "http://www.yahoo.com/"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Get the web view settings instance
        val setting = webview.settings;

        // Enable java script in web view
        setting.javaScriptEnabled = true

        webview.loadUrl(url)

    }
}
```

I also have inserted a WebView component into activity_main.xml with an id of **@+id/webview**.  When the app loads, the screen redirects to a chrome browser where the Yahoo page is loaded.  How do I maintain the browser within the app?

I have tried adding `webview.setWebViewRenderProcessClient = webViewClient()` before the URL loads, but I get an unresolved reference error when I compile the code.

**EDIT**

The XML is as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have also added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` to the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: There's nothing in your code that would make the default browser open when you load the URL. Do you have any attributes set in your XML layout perhaps?

Comment: Ok, I just tried the code and it seems like it has something to do with your URL. Try with `google.com` for instance and it shouldn't open the default browser, but just load the website.
Try overriding the `WebViewClient` also as stated in this SO thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12802173/882251

Comment: @Darwind correct- when I use Google, the browser loads within the app.  Trying WebViewClient override now...

Comment: Changing ```webview.webViewRenderProcessClient = webViewClient()``` to ```webview.webViewClient = WebViewClient()``` has done the job!  Thanks.  Add it as an answer and I'll mark it as correct?

Comment: You should probably just delete the question as I found the other question and answer by a quick search on Google :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android webview launches browser when calling loadurl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746409/android-webview-launches-browser-when-calling-loadurl)

Comment: @Darwind I'll leave this on here as it relates to Kotlin rather than Java

Comment: It's not really Kotlin related per se, but sure. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement `WebView`'s `webClient` and set it before calling `webView.loadUrl = "#someURL"`.
Example:

```
webview.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
```

For further details regarding `WebView` check [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/managing-webview)