# How to catch a website redirect in a webview

Tags: android, redirect, webview, paypal

I'm trying to setup inapp PayPal MECL transactions.

After the transaction is completed or failed, PayPal will redirect to a fail url or transaction completed url..

How can i catch that url to see if the transaction is completed?

Comment: use an intent filter that matches your url

Comment: thnx, i think that will solve my problem

Comment: are you using a costume webview?

Comment: @njzk2 yeah..but if I search for something on that very page ,then also url will be matched.There I don't want to do anything. I just want to catch the redirects .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple options

**Intent Filter:**

```
  <activity android:name=".ActivityTest">
    <intent-filter><action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
      <data android:host="www.mywebsite.com" android:scheme="http"></data>
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
```

As described here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/C6qNOBULpCc
And official docs here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html

Or **WebViewClient**:

[Clicking URLs opens default browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378800/android-webview-click-opens-default-browser)