# Does WebView need a WebViewClient to work?

Tags: android, android-webview

I was going through android tutorials and tried out the `WebView` example. This is what I ended up with:

**WebAppActivity**

```
public class WebAppActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        wv.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

    }
}
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </WebView>

</LinearLayout>
```

But instead of loading the page in the application itself, as soon as the application starts the default android browser opens and the page loads in the browser instead of the application. When I press back I return to the application activity which displays a blank screen.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Edit:

**manifest**

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".WebAppActivity" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

This was just to show that I have added the INTERNET permission

Edit :

As soon as I add a `WebViewClient`,

```
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {});
```

the page loads in the application. Is this expected behaviour? Does an Android WebView **require** a WebViewClient?
(couldn't find any documentation on it)

Edit :

I noticed that this problem occurs when I install the apk in an emulator which has the Google APIs. On a normal emulator (without the Google APIs) it behaves as expected.

Comment: your question is already answered on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378800/android-webview-click-opens-default-browser

Comment: @silent Please read carefully. That is not my question. I am having trouble loading the first page itself, which loads in the browser instead of the application. See Flo's comment

Comment: No I don't think he's talking about links in the web page itself that got clicked. This sounds like the web page is never loaded in the WebView at all.

Comment: Here is a detailed example: **[Android - WebView client example](http://goo.gl/zcWUq)**, agree with you @silent.

Comment: @PareshMayani Even the first page isn't loaded. I am talking about link clicks. The very first page I am trying to load using `webView.loadUrl("http://google.com")` isn't being loaded. It directly invokes the browser. Is that expected behaviour?

Comment: @PareshMayani: Deleted my answer as it's of no use anymore.. :)  +1@Aki for question edit..

Comment: Please refer my answer below. It may help you understand why the first page doesn't load in you application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you have to set a WebViewClient that returns true on the overridden method 'shouldOverrideUrlLoading' so that your webview loads the URL in your app.

Let me know if you want an example.

---

Edit

@Aki [WebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29)

> Give the host application a chance to take over the control when a new url is about to be loaded in the current WebView. **If WebViewClient is not provided, by default WebView will ask Activity Manager to choose the proper handler for the url**. If WebViewClient is provided, return true means the host application handles the url, while return false means the current WebView handles the url.

Comment: @Christopher Why is it that we need a webViewClient only in case of devices with google apis. Moreover, can you point me to some official Android documentation which states this fact?

Comment: Thanks Christopher. But it does not say anywhere that `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` is called when we invoke the `loadUrl` method.

Answer (score 1):

For loading a webpage from url into a webview, there is no need to setting webview client. Without webview client you can load a webpage into your webview. But WebViewClient brings many advantages for handling the webview. Sample usage for loading webpage from url,

```
webView.loadUrl(yoururl);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private WebView webVenue;
private WebSettings websettings;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.schedule_time);

        webVenue = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview_schedule_time);
        txtEmptyMsg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtEmptyMsg);

        mContext = this;        
        webVenue.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webVenue.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        websettings=webVenue.getSettings();
        webVenue.setScrollBarStyle(ScrollView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webVenue.loadUrl(URL);
}
}
```

All The Best...

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I **know** other ways to get it working. For example adding a `WebViewClient` gets it working. Getting it to work isn't my concern. Finding out why it is not working, is.

Comment: It loads the webpage inside the application? Or in the Android browser?

Comment: i think while simply using loadurl(),will open url in browser

Comment: yup, deleted my comment as it's no longer related to your current situation.

Answer (score 0):

No not quite but it allows you to do a lot of stuff.

Note that making a call to shouldOverrideUrlLoading in the WebViewClient doesn’t seem to work either, so you should do your processing in onPageFinished.

Here is a [blog post](http://abdulapopoola.wordpress.com/2012/01/14/how-to-display-a-webpage-in-a-dialog-in-android/) that'll guide you through.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason the url is opened in default android browser is because of "wv.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");"

When you load http://www.google.com, the google website actually redirects the page to http://www.google.co.in (assuming you are launching the app from India).

If you run "wv.loadUrl("http://www.google.co.in");", google will not redirect the page and the first page will be opened in your application and further clicks will be opened in the system browser.

To handle this further clicks you need the WebViewClient.