# Does Android's Stock Web Browser use WebViewClient?

Tags: android, android-webview, webviewclient

If I understand correctly, every WebView based implementation [needs WebViewClient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8827476/1124861).

But looking at the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.2_r1.1/com/android/browser/BrowserActivity.java) for Android 2.2's browser, I can't find any mention of WebViewClient.

How does it work if it doesn't use it?

If it does use it, where is it "hiding"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is implemented inside the tabs (see [Tab.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.2_r1.1/com/android/browser/Tab.java?av=f#446)).

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there a systematic method to finding this type of information? Or better yet... how did you find out that WebViewClient is inside `Tab.java`?

Comment: Answering myself: My Firefox's `Find` text-search doesn't find `WebViewClient` in the decorated version of the source code for some reason, but it finds it without any problem in the [Raw](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.2_r1.1/com/android/browser/BrowserActivity.java/?v=source) version (available by clicking the [Raw](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.2_r1.1/com/android/browser/BrowserActivity.java/?v=source) link). So using the raw version seems to be the method.