# about loadUrl() in Android WebView

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

```
Kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var myWebView: WebView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        myWebView = findViewById(R.id.webView)

        // webView setting
        myWebView.webViewClient = MyWebViewClient()
        myWebView.loadUrl("www.naver.com")
    }


    inner class MyWebViewClient: WebViewClient() {
        override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url)
            myProgressBar.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    }
}
```

This code is my android code.

I understand that the WebViewClient class prevents new windows from opening. However, I cannot find the reason for how it prevents new windows from opening. What is the principle by which the WebViewClient class prevents new windows from opening?

I tried to find a solution with ChatGPT and Google, but I couldn't find the answer I was looking for. I don't trust ChatGPT because its reliability is low.

Comment: what kind of new window is it? Do you want it will be open in others browser app?

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I am practicing with Android WebView, and when I use WebViewClient like the above code, the URL is connected to the internal WebView of the app, but if I don't use it, it is connected to the default browser in the Android device. I am curious about the reason for this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does WebView need a WebViewClient to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740307/does-webview-need-a-webviewclient-to-work)

Comment: Thank you :), but that's not the answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

> > myWebView.loadUrl("www.naver.com")
> > }

You should specify a protocol like

```
myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.naver.com")
}
```

or

```
myWebView.loadUrl("https://www.naver.com")
}
```

Comment: Thank you:), but that's not the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: Then which answer are you looking for?