# Android WebView Issue

Tags: android, webview

I have developed an app named "Rockfish Motorsports" case u wanna dl it :)
Anyways when the app loads the page, instead of loading it in the webview, it opens up a browser?
Heres the coding if u can  help

RMS/res/layout/main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

 <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

 <WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/webview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="XXXXXXX"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/new_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".RockfishMotorsportsActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
 </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: add your activity source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find the app on the Android Market, but I'm assuming your webview you include is trying to go to a different page on user action, which by default will launch the browser. To make the new page load in your WebView, check out this other SO answer:

[Android WebView click opens default browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378800/android-webview-click-opens-default-browser)