# Webview loads url in browser window instead of Webview

Tags: android

I want to display the webview,admob and a navbar which contains an edit text and 2 buttons in the same page.But the page automatically goes to the webview (as in the browser) hiding the other elements defined in the activity....The code is given below...please give your valuable suggestions...Thank you in advance...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
    <include android:id="@+id/nav_bar_layout" layout="@layout/nav_bar" android:layout_above="@+id/web_view" />
    <WebView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/web_view" android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
    <include android:id="@+id/admob_layout" layout="@layout/admob_layout" android:layout_below="@+id/web_view" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: a piece of code could be very helpful.

Comment: Well,I got the solution...
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378800/android-webview-click-opens-default-browser

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use setWebViewClient(). Setting your own custom WebViewClient lets you handle onPageFinished, shouldOverrideUrlLoading.

```
webview=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.htm");
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Comment: But Another problem followed the Web page doesn't load...It shows a blank screen....

Comment: see the edited code: you can add any web page and load it in webview using loadUrl method. here i have added index.htm page under assets folder

Answer (score 0):

Use ScrollView. As content of webview will be more so it will occupy whole screen if you have given as android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Or Else given fix height to webview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:background="@drawable/bg_2">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Title"
       />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/txtDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtDescription"
      />

 </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```