# Prevent WebView from Opening the Browser

Tags: android, webview, browser, android-webview

**I'm already active JavaScript for a given WebView, and opens new link inside the WebView, not in the Browser.** 
This Is Main Activity

```
    package com.Afrogfx.pronouns;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.webkit.WebView;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    public class MainActivityPronouns extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity_pronouns);

    WebView wvHtml = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    wvHtml.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    wvHtml.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wvHtml.loadUrl("http://afrogfx.com/appcatcategories.php?catid=13&parentid=11");
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main_activity_pronouns, menu);
    return true;
    }
    }
```

**how can i handel my code to open all link in site inside the WebView (App) , not in the Browser & ( don't show to user Open in browser).**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clicking URLs opens default browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378800/clicking-urls-opens-default-browser)

Answer (score 30):

For that just create the subclass that is extending webclient and use the method of that class onPageFinished(WebView c,String url) and
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(final WebView view, final String url)

here is the code-

```
 myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()       
        {
             @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
            {
                //view.loadUrl(url);
                System.out.println("hello");
                return false;
            }
        });
        myWebView.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: The docs say you should return false to continue loading that url. returning true will abort loading

Comment: I agree with @henon, it should be false

Answer (score 12):

In case you use Kotlin:

```
webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
                override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
                    view: WebView?,
                    request: WebResourceRequest?
                ): Boolean {
                    return false
                }
            }
```

Answer (score -2):

so you have to use WebviewClicent .. here is the class

```
private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient 
{
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(final WebView view, final String url) 
    {
        Utils.showActivityViewer(WebsiteActivity.this);
        new Thread(new Runnable() 
        {

            public void run()
            {
                view.loadUrl(url);
            }



            }).start();  



        return true;
    }
}
```

and bind in a webview as

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
```

and refer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html

Comment: Welcome to "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.” exception )