# Can Webview make links display without opening new window/browser?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [android webview click opens default browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378800/android-webview-click-opens-default-browser)

I have Webview that works for bringing in site, but when I click on links other than the original link it opens a browser.  Is there any way to have those links reopen/load within the same webview?  Is there a WebView options for this?

Answer (score 1):

it is easy.

1.first， you should write your own WebViewClient,
eg:

```
class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }
    }
```

2.now ,you can use it in your Activity,
eg:

```
WebView view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
view.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    view.loadUrl("http://www.baidu.com");
```

Hope can help you !