# WebView shows Choose Action Dialog, does not navigate

Tags: android, android-webview

Given the following code, the WebView will not navigate to and display google.com but instead a Choose Action Dialog will pop up with all installed browser apps to choose from.
Is this intended and is there a fix for this imo weird behaviour?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    WebView webview = new WebView(this);
    setContentView(webview);

    WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Clicking URLs opens default browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378800/android-webview-click-opens-default-browser)

Essentially, you'll have to provide your own WebClient and override shouldOverrideUrlLoading

```
private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```