# Creating runnable and running a while script inside on Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, runnable

Right now I have a webview being loaded, and then after it's loaded, I have a Runnable started with a while loop inside of it - I want to monitor the URL in the webview for changes.  However, `url` can't be resolved inside the Runnable:

```
mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        mWebview.scrollTo(681, 100);
    }
});

//BREAK 

new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        while(url.contains("displaylogin")) {
```

Is there any way to monitor an element in the UI thread with a Runnable?  Or am I going about this the wrong way, and there's a better way to continuously monitor the URL for changes?

Comment: I found this thread: [How to “Monitor” the URL base in WebView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15937907/how-to-monitorthe-url-base-in-webview), but the `if else` statement only checks once, and then quits.

Comment: You don't need a Runnable. All you need to do is override the shouldOverrideUrlLoading and inspect the URL and return true or false based on what your condition.