# How can I hide the URL bar from an Android browser

Tags: android, url

I want to hide the URL bar from the browser permanently, and it should not appear even if the person gets redirected from one page to another.
Here is my .java code:

```
package com.example.com.android.royalcastleapp;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
public class Bookinghome extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bookinghome);
        //Get a reference of WebView holder
        WebView webview = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webview);
        //Get the settings
        WebSettings websettings = webview.getSettings();
        //Enable Javascript
        websettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        //Make the zoom controls visible
        websettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        //Load the default url.
        webview.loadUrl("http//okRoom.aspx");   
    }
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_bookinghome, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

And here is my layout:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <WebView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        tools:context=".Bookinghome" 
        android:id= "@+id/webview"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

If anyone could suggest any changes I could make, that would be great!

Answer (score 2):

Your application starts default browser.

You need to use WebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading like described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2379054/2183804

Comment: i didn't asked that sir, what i want is to hide the adress bar from the browser, can u plz tell

Comment: @user1643227: `WebView` does not have an address bar, and so there is nothing to hide there. You cannot attack third-party apps, such as trying to "hide the adress bar from the browser". Instead, you need to follow the instructions in this answer to keep the user within your `WebView`, rather than opening up the browser on links and redirects.

Comment: @user1643227 : The answer is correct - if you are not using `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(...)` then Android will use the stock (built-in) browser app and there is nothing you can do to hide it's address bar.