# WebPage loading on browser instead of Webview in Activity

Tags: android, android-webview

In my xml file I'm having text and below that text,I have placed a webview.
I am trying to open google's home page in Webview. Instead of opening in webview,webpage is opening on browser.What I want is web page should load in webview which is below some text.Below is my code:

```
           <TextView
                  android:id="@+id/txt"

                  android:text="Hello Android"
                  android:textSize="30sp"
                  android:textStyle="bold"
                  android:textColor="#003399"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                  />

      <WebView 

                 android:id="@+id/webview"
                 android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                 android:layout_below="@id/txt"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
```

Kindly help to solve this.Thank you

Comment: Make sure you override `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` as detailed here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2379054/833647

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because a combination of two things:

1. the WebViewClient is not set (set to null), this makes the WebView try and offer every navigation as an intent to the system. Since you have a browser installed the system will try to handle that navigation there.
2. going to google.com ususally results in a redirect, which is why the stuff about navigations in the previous point matters.

Try this:

```
webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your activity and than use this code...

> mWebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
>             mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript
>
> ```
>       mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
>           public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,String description, String failingUrl) {
>               Toast.makeText(youractivity_name.this, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>           }
>       });
>
>       mWebview.loadUrl("http://www.yahoo.com");
> ```