# javascript location.reload() webview opens external browser

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-webview

This question is related to this [Android 4.4.x WebView opens a tab in the browser when using location.reload()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20510071/android-4-4-x-webview-opens-a-tab-in-the-browser-when-using-location-reload) .

I have a webview app and in the html page, I have some jquery script which will reload the page.

The jquery script is as below:

```
                if (lng > 1) {
                    $this.closest('.single-broker').remove();
                }
                if (lng === 1) {
                    location.reload();
                }
```

in an ajax success function.

However, the `location.reload()` will open the same page in external browser. I'm already following the suggestion which given in linked question.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: The general consensus is to call `loadUrl()` again through webview to load the URL rather than trying to reload the page using regular Javascript as this may invoke a browser method. A more in depth look at your methods may offer more insight however.