# URL opened in browser instead of web view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview

I am using below code to open a link in web view -

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
            mWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
            mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
            mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            mWebView.loadUrl(link);
```

But it opens the link in browser.
I want that the url should only open in my web view. Is there any mistake in the code. Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Set WebViewClient in webView Like this mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clicking URLs opens default browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378800/clicking-urls-opens-default-browser)

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `WebViewClient` of your webview and set it. Like it is mentioned in one of the comments on your question.

`mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());`

And google first, you may not need to post the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should init WebViewClient: `mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient())`

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
 webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {  
      @Override  
      public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {  
        //set URL Here
        return false;  
      }  
    }
```