# How to make substring as a link and on click of that link open local webview rather than web browser

Tags: android, webview

I have a task to make substring as a link and open local html page in web view rather than web browser.

For example, there is a string of

"You have to accept **Terms and Condition** to register."

Here Terms and Condition is a substring and on click of that link I have to open html page in webview

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clicking URLs opens default browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378800/clicking-urls-opens-default-browser)

Comment: Essentially, all you need to do is `myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());`.

Comment: You have set that string for a textview. Am a right?

Comment: I dont want to open webview on click of whole string but want to open on a sub string of particular string

Comment: @ Sree14, Yes I put string as a textview but how can I get click listener of a sub string. I dont want to click whole string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("You have to accept Terms and Condition to register.");
    ClickableSpan termsClickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View textView) {
            // Call the webview activity.
        }

        @Override
        public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {

        }
    };
ss.setSpan(termsClickableSpan, 20, 39, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
textView.setText(ss);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Here you have to use SpannableString and set the ClickableSpan to those text that you need to be clicked. Here, 2nd and 3rd parameter of setSpan method denotes the start and end of the text to be clicked.