# How to make mobile site to android app

Tags: android, mobile

I have developed a mobile site. And now I want to convert that to an android app.

I am not so good in android. Can any one tell me where i can convert my mobile site to android app. Or do we have any software to do so. Or any tutorial site.

I need to integrate adds in my app too.

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: I recommend you to develop native app as you have already had mobile site(m.site). If don't have experience in mobile app development, needless to say to hire a freelancer.

Answer (score 1):

Create an application using android studio with Blank activity and update the layout file to use WebView to load your website.

You can follow this documentation https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html to load url.

You can add WebView like this example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

And in your activity load your url as follows

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
```

and if you want handle all links in that html to be opened in the same app follows this [Clicking URLs opens default browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378800/clicking-urls-opens-default-browser)

Answer (score 1):

Meant to mention it as a comment but haven't got enough reputation yet.

Follow [santosh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40337094/6382313) if you don't need to make any changes for the android application, otherwise, I think it is a great opportunity for a web developer to learn hybrid mobile application development (i.e. writing cross-platform mobile apps using your web development skills). [Cordova docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/) might be a great place to start.