# Access all website in cordova app using android webview

Tags: android, cordova

I'm, trying to access one java web application in cordova app. But every time browser open-up. Suggest me code for use Webview in cordova app.

Answer (score 1):

please verify in your config.xml, that the tag launch-external is set to 'no'

```
<access origin="https://your_url.com/*" launch-external="no" />
```

Comment: Still open browser. Can you tell me how to use WebView in Cordova app? I use this: WebView myWebView = null;
myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.url.com");  But it is applicable to only one page then another pages are re-direct to browser.

Comment: Please check this link, it explain how to do it as you wish :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378800/clicking-urls-opens-default-browser   but my advise is to not change the java code and use the plugin cordova "InAppBrowser"