# Android/Java - functional website inside the app using webView

Tags: android, user-interface, android-webview

I am trying to make an Android app that displays a website. I got that to work, yet when I am clicking buttons inside the web application, it takes me out of the app to view it. How can I prevent that from happening?

Here's my **MainActivity.java**

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    WebView wv;
    String mypage = "http://bizmeetz.com/";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv. setFocusable(true);
        wv.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        wv.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        wv.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        wv.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        wv.loadUrl(mypage);

    }
}
```

This is an updated version and still did not work. MainActivity still shows an error.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    WebView wv;
    String mypage = "http://bizmeetz.com/";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv. setFocusable(true);
        wv.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        wv.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        wv.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        wv.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        wv.loadUrl(mypage);
        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your own WebViewClient.

It would look something like this:

```
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

You can also check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2379054/4632435 for better explanation.

Edit 1:

It turns out that the default behavior of WebViewClient is what you want, so you just need to implement it.

Also, if you are loading a complex website, you should take a look at WebChromeClient.

Comment: It didn't work, I added it like this. Look above for the updated code.